# Upper bound on volume growth

Tags: riemannian-geometry

If the Ricci curvature of a compact Riemannian manifold of demsnion $n$ is greater than 1-n, does it follow that the volume entropy satisfies $$\liminf_{r\rightarrow \infty} \frac{\log vol B_r(p)}{r}\leq n-1$$

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this follows from the [Bishop-Gromov volume comparison theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bishop%E2%80%93Gromov_inequality).